# How to get list of active users in iis 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

How do I retrieve list of Active users (with account ids) in IIS 6.

Comment: If you mean programatically, search for Active Directory classes (and specify language/requirements). If you mean IIS6 the server - your question belongs at ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you mean active VISITORS on your site rather than active USERS, and the fact that I see that you're using asp.net... you could try the code below.

GLOBAL.ASAX

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
'Set the initial CurrentNumberOfUsers count to zero
Application("CurrentNumberOfUsers") = 0
 End Sub

 Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
' Add the newest user to the CurrentNumberOfUsers count
Application("CurrentNumberOfUsers") += 1
 End Sub

 Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
' Remove the last user from the CurrentNumberOfUsers count
Application("CurrentNumberOfUsers") -= 1
 End Sub
```

and then to retrieve that in your page, you would use something like

```
label1.text = Application("CurrentNumberOfUsers")
```

Now if you are trying to get the number of registerd users, you could try something like this.

```
Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
```

And if you need the total number of users on your site, you can use

```
Membership.GetAllUsers.Count()
```

As for the "With Account ID's" part... mmmm, not sure... prolly have to loop through each active account and pull it's ID.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring
What namespace has Membership ,does this imply that i must use Membership in my application ?
Thanks - tony

Comment: does your application authenticate users?  If so, how? Are you usign Active Directory?  If so, check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for..Yes, using ADS with little modification to my ADS library code I could get things done..

Answer (score 0):

II6 doesn't store user accounts and therefore doesn't expose any functionality to return user accounts.